# Nodejs ndb installation ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, ubuntu-18.04, chromium, google-chrome-headless

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04**

Using nvm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndb

installed ndb successfully **+ ndb@1.1.5**

But having an error when I am trying to run **ndb server.js**

```
Downloading Chromium r624492...
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492!
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:108:27)
    at downloadChromium (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:194:50)
    at findChrome (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:241:32)
    at Object.launch (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/carlo.js:594:42)
    at launch (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/lib/launcher.js:23:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/ndb.js:35:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
unhandledRejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'executablePath' of null
    at findChrome (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:242:43)
    at async Object.launch (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/carlo.js:594:36)
    at async launch (/home/bacillus/.nvm/versions/node/v12.17.0/lib/node_modules/ndb/lib/launcher.js:23:11)
```

Comment: This looks more like a connection problem than a problem with chromium installation itself

Comment: If you are behind a corporate firewall, can you try setting your proxy(HTTPS_PROXY env var) and trying again?

Comment: I am new in web dev, tried every solution found in askubuntu, GitHub, and StackOverflow   regarding this problem but didn't found luck.

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan what will be  proxy configuration, address and port

Comment: @Lord Are you behind a corporate proxy firewall?

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan no I am not, this is my private home broadband internet connection.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am running into the same problem.

Comment: @ZHANGLuyao, No, I failed to solve the problem, if you find one please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install ndb with this command :
   `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=1 sudo npm install -g ndb --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root ftw`
2. Then run `ndb server.js`

Answer (score 0):

NDB needs the module Puppeteer in order to work. you MUST install that first, THEN install NDB.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndb    - Heres the link to the package

> npm install -g puppeteer

This will install Puppeteer globally

Then you can run ndb normally.

> ndb server.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).